# Drag and Drop swap in divs not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make the drag and drop swap work in visible divs, but it won't work. When I try applying the code `drop="swapDrop(event)"` to the visible divs, the image just directly swaps with the visible div, instead of going inside the visible div. Without the `drop="swapDrop(event)"`, the images are not able to swap inside the visible divs. And also when I drag an image from the invisible divs to the visible divs, the image coming from the invisible div will vanish. Also, inside the invisible divs, there is supposed to be a swap.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body bgcolor="H70D4R334">
<title>Ordinate</title>
<head>
    <style text/css> 

 #div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  border: 0px solid blue;
}

#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 0px solid blue;
}

#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

#div4 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

#div5 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

#div6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

#div7 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

#div8 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  border: 0px solid green;
}

#div10 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div11 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div12 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div13 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div14 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div15 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div16 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#div17 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#Button {
  float: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
}


</style>



<script>
var dragSrcEl = null;
var draggSrcID = null;

    function dragStart(ev) {
    draggSrcID = ev.target.id;
    dragSrcEl = ev.target;
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', ev.target.outerHTML);
    }

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggSrcID));
        ev.preventDefault();
    } 

    function swapDrop(ev) {

      if (ev.stopPropagation) {
        ev.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
      }

      // Don't do anything if dropping the same image we're dragging.
      if (dragSrcEl != ev.target) {
        // Set the source image to the HTML of the image we're dropping on.
        srcEl = document.getElementById(draggSrcID);
        srcEl.outerHTML = ev.target.outerHTML;
        ev.target.outerHTML = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
       }
        ev.preventDefault();
    }       

</script>   
</head>
<body>
<center><font size="10">Ordinate</font></center>
    <div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div13" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div14" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div15" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div16" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    </div>
    <div id="div17" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div> 
    <div id="div1" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="D" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=D&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" />
    </div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="E" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=E&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
    </div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="I" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=I&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">  
    </div>
    <div id="div4" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    <img id="T" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=T&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
    </div>
    <div id="div5" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    <img id="A" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=A&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
    </div>
    <div id="div6" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    <img id="N" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=N&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">  
    </div>
    <div id="div7" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    <img id="O" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=O&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
    </div>
    <div id="div8" ondrop="swapDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
    <img id="R" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=R&w=50&h=50" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">  
    </div>
    <center><input id="Button" type="submit" value="Click me to check" onclick="HitEnter()"></center>
    <script>
        word = "ordinate"
        function HitEnter() {
            for (i = 10, str = ""; i <= 17; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById("div" + i).childNodes.length > 1) {
                    str += document.getElementById("div" + i).childNodes[1].id
                }
            }
            if (str.toLowerCase() == word) {
                alert("Good job!!!")
            }
            else {
            alert('You got the word incorrect! Please try again.')

            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be very helpful if you could directly edit the code, because I am a beginner.

here is the link if you want to directly edit the code: https://jsfiddle.net/wyq5oke1/2/

I will appreciate any answers, and for people who are viewing, I would highly appreciate that you find a friend that can solve it (if they know how).

Comment: #div1,div2, ... 17, use the css like this, your code is very hard to look at - >  <style text/.css>  this is wrong too this is good - > <style type="text/css">

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfyrorng/ . editable

Comment: I edited the code a little bit, and that makes it a little easier to work with.

Comment: Seriously, can someone please answer?